# How to specify local machine to locally running web application by name?

Tags: .net, security, web-applications, ldap

I am debugging a locally (localhost) running .NET web application.  The application requires me to specify a machine by name in order to view a certain page.  I have no idea what name to enter.  The application asks for the following information:

```
Computer Name (Active Directory Computer Name)
DNS Name
```

Answer (score 3):

Open a command prompt and type `hostname`. This will give you the computer name.

To find the DNS name use `nslookup` with your IP address as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

your best bet here is to look at the actual code to see what it is doing.  If the code is asking for you to type the local machine name then it stands to reason that it might be comparing it to some value that the code is able to acquire.

Just run the same method that the code uses to get the correct value to enter...